# How do I find a Generator Matrix from Parity Check Matrix if the Parity Check Matrix is not in the systematic form?

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

Given the Parity Check Matrix of code $C$
[image]

How do I find the generator matrix for code $C$? The parity check matrix is not in the systematic form.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your code is the nullspace (kernel) of the given matrix. So find a basis for the nullspace of your matrix. This gives you a basis for your code, from which you can get a generator matrix.

Comment: So basis for the nullspace of $H$ gives a basis for code $C$. After that, we put the basis of $C$ as rows in the new matrix, and this new matrix is the generator matrix for code $C$? Am I right?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: By the way, can we just make $H$ into the standard form $(A | I_{n-k})$ by doing some elementary row operations and then from the standard form of $H$, we find the generator matrix of $C$ by making into $(I_k | -A^T)$?